# Is it always possible to convert a non-deterministic PDA to a deterministic one?

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar

Is it always possible to convert a non-deterministic PDA to a deterministic one? What is the significance of this observation for the computing power of contex-free grammars?

Comment: Did you check the Wikipedia page on [deterministic PDAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_pushdown_automaton)? It states that nondeterministic PDAs are strictly more powerful than deterministic, but does not explicitly give a counterexample. See Sipser's book for details. // I do not understand your second question.

Comment: grammars are used in language design. parsing simpler languages is much easier than parsing more powerful ones. Google for "LR grammars".

Answer (score 4):

The class of languages recognised by a deterministic pda is the class of [deterministic context-free languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language). This is a strict subclass of the class of context-free languages. An example of a context-free language that is not deterministic context-free is the language of even-length palindromes over $0$ and $1$.